# How Do I Improve A Huge Many-To-Many Django Query To Improve Django Speed?

Tags: django, postgresql, iterator, many-to-many, database-performance

I have a query set like this that I need to optimize because I think this query set slows down the website performance.  The user_wishlist field is a many-to-many DB relational relationship to an Account model/table.  How do I?

```
product_wishlist_store_list = []  
non_paged_products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('user_wishlist').select_related('category').filter(is_available=True).order_by('created_date')
for product in non_paged_products.iterator():
      # Get User Wishlist
      try:
            product_wishlist = product.user_wishlist.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()
            if product_wishlist:
                product_wishlist_store_list.append(product.id)
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

So when I turn on the log for a DEBUG purpose in Django, I see that there are nearly a thousand *(0.000) SELECT* queries of *INNER JOIN*.  Does the 0.000 mean there is no hit to the database or is it?  Still, seeing a thousand queries like that kind of scary to me -- I feel this code is so inefficient.  Is it?

Comment: It's odd you decided to add a Product.wishlist->User Many-To-Many on the Product Model, instead of User.wishlist -> Product on the User Model..  but you could always look into doing a Cache, It wouldn't help the query speed, but you'd do it less often- once per user when they first login and then update it when they add a new item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use simple ORM query here and do a values list at the end, this would reduce your code and query timing by a lot.

```
    product_wishlist_store_list = Product.objects.filter(
        is_available=True, 
        user_wishlist__id=id=request.user.id
    ).order_by('created_date').distinct().values_list("id", flat=True)
```

Something like this should work for you.

Comment: OK, Vabha lodha, your answer is correct.  It's just that the code you'd written got an error.  With fixing it up like this:     if request.user.is_authenticated:
        product_wishlist_store_list = Product.objects.filter(is_available=True, user_wishlist__id=request.user.id).order_by(
            'created_date').distinct().values_list("id", flat=True) -- this works perfectly.  I'm going to give you a check mark and an upvote.